# Android PandaBoard: Linux terminal output for debugging?

Tags: reboot, fastboot, usb-debugging

My research team is currently considering investing in a PandaBoard for Android b/c we are developing a custom kernel/sys-image and would like Linux terminal output.

Does the Pandaboard give me booting information?  Such as printing kernel messages to the Linux terminal as the board loads up the system image?  So for example, if the phone crashes, I can at least see how far the phone made it in the boot process.

Comment: Is this related to this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26123/android-boot-up-messages-for-debugging ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find some sure way of getting console output of the boot process.  It seems that everything that I've tried so far relies on the phone booting successfully, which means there's no developing options available to non-Android developers when the phone doesn't make it to a stable state.  I want to see what's going on inside the phone, but don't want to engage in hardware destroying practices such as soldering.

We're trying to weigh the different options available.  This one would cost money though, so we want to know what the PandaBoard can do.

Comment: It might be best to check out the google newsgroups specifically related to android-kernel and android-building, there is a lot of similar types of questions relating to pandaboard like what you're asking for... it might be helpful and worth your while to check as I feel the pandaboard related matters is a bit too localized for this forum.. :)

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Bootloader_Project) for the general idea.

For verification, do the following steps:

1. Connect DB9 to your host (PC) <------> Panda board (target). You need to connect with minicom and mini USB for adb shell.

   ```
   pc$ sudo minicom
   ```
2. You should have adb shell for the Android SDK.

   ```
   pc$ export PATH=$PATH://android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
   ```
3. Reboot the panda board.

   ```
   pc$ adb devices # to check the device is connected or not
   pc$ adb reboot   # to reboot
   ```

On minicom terminal, you will get logs of the reboot. At the end, it will ask you to hit a key to stop auto boot. This will tell you if the device is getting the image or not. If you want to boot manuually by using U-Boot terminal, press key so you will get U-Boot terminal.

```
 hardware_name# bootm
```

This will help you a little bit.