# How to diagnose bootloop?

Tags: twrp, boot-loop

My Sony Xperia Z5 sometimes heats up, starts lagging and crashes after a few minutes to end up in a boot loop. I have the teamwin recovery project 3.1.1-0 installed and the phone is rooted with magisk on Android 7.

Usually, it was enough to keep power and volume down pressed, enter the recovery, and choose "reboot" to get out of the bootloop. This time, it seems different, so I'm caring a bit more now.

What are steps to take for finding the reason of and/or getting out of the bootloop?
I have access to a terminal through the recovery.

I have used a script called `mm` that I had lying around on my sdcard and that I have used before when I had a bootloop due to a broken magisk module, to activate "Core Only Mode" which is supposed to deactivate the loading of any magisk modules. So I assume that the problem is actually not magisk.
Also, I haven't updated magisk, modules, or the system since at least a few months, so it would be weird if that were it.

Wiping the dalvik cache as adviced by the [boot-loop tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) did not help either.

The tag wiki for logging sent me to [android boot up messages for debugging](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26126/96334) which recommends a few things.  But `/proc/last_kmsg` is inexistent, dmesg is more output than I know what to do with, especially much recovery stuff which I don't care about, and `adb logcat` won't react because the device crashes before it is found.

The boot process crashes at the xperia logo - so before the animation

Comment: See [tag:logging] and [tag:logcat] wiki's and questions